# Why can't I use Column Alias in Having Clouse with Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I run (simplified)

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT student ORDER BY student SEPARATOR ', ') student_GROUP_CONCAT
  FROM report_checklists
 GROUP 
    BY date
HAVING (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT student ORDER BY student SEPARATOR ', ') != '') 
 LIMIT 2500;
```

This works fine in Laravel 6.x and phpMyAdmin.

Now I change to

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT student ORDER BY student SEPARATOR ', ') student_GROUP_CONCAT
  FROM report_checklists
 GROUP 
    BY date
HAVING (student_GROUP_CONCAT != '') 
 LIMIT 2500;
```

and this returns an empty result in Laravel but not in phpMyAdmin.

Doc says I may use Column Alias in Having: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Do anyone have an Idea why this happens? Thank you. I spend 3h to figure this issue out.

Comment: Please include exception generated by laravel and also how you are executing this query in laravel

Comment: Thanks for your response There is no exception. Just an empty result. But not in phpmyadmin

Comment: please add an [mre]

Comment: I cannot replicate this observation

Comment: Thanks for all your responses! I just updated all Components. Now the error is gone.